# Hung returning Follows data from Relationships endpoint

Tags: c#, instagram-api, instasharp

I'm trying to return a list of followed users from the Instagram API. I'm on a sandbox account using the *InstaSharp* wrapper for .NET.

The action method is being called after user is authenticated.

```
public ActionResult Following()
{
    var oAuthResponse = Session["InstaSharp.AuthInfo"] as OAuthResponse;

    if (oAuthResponse == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    var info = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Relationships(config_, oAuthResponse);

    var following = info.Follows("10").Result;

    return View(following.Data);
}
```

Comment: Show the whole Action method and also how it is being called. Most likely you are mixing async and blocking calls ie: `.Result` which runs the risk of causing a deadlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the method async all the way through instead of making the blocking call `.Result` which runs the risk of causing a deadlock

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Following() {
    var oAuthResponse = Session["InstaSharp.AuthInfo"] as OAuthResponse;

    if (oAuthResponse == null) {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    var info = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Relationships(config_, oAuthResponse);

    var following = await info.Follows("10");

    return View(following.Data);
}
```

depending on how `info.Follows` was implemented.

Looking at the [Github repo](https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp/blob/master/src/InstaSharp/Extensions/HttpClientExtensions.cs), the API internally makes a call to a method defined like this

```
public static async Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage request)
```

Which looks like your smoking gun as calling `.Result` higher up the call stack on this task would result in your experienced deadlock.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: okay, Data is returning 0 results. Not sure if this is a limitation with sandbox apps..

Comment: @Tariq But it has stopped hanging? whick was the original problem right? I do not know enough about that API. I was just identifying what are the known causes of the problem you described originally.